# how to configure rollupJs to convert nodeJs script to es6 module?

Tags: node.js, es6-modules, commonjs, rollupjs

I would like to configure one script `findFruit.js` that is written under nodeJs, wrapping into a library and make it useful from the other project that may be written by nodeJs or es6 code. How should I configure rollup from a es6 module?
I get the error once using

```
import * as obj from './application'
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

```
//~/application/src/findFruit.js
function findFruit() {
  return 'banana'
}
module.export = findFruit
//~/application/package.json
{
  "name": "get a fruit",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "author": "author",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "main": "dist/findFruit.js",
  "scripts": {
    "publish": "rm -rf ./dist && rollup -c rollup.config.js",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^15.0.0",
    "rollup": "^2.26.11",
    "rollup-plugin-auto-external": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
//~/application/rollup.config.js
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import pkg from "./package.json";
import autoExternal from "rollup-plugin-auto-external";
export default {
  input: 'src/findFruit.js',
  plugins: [autoExternal(), commonjs()],
  output: {
    file: pkg.main,
    format: 'cjs',
    exports: 'named',
  },
};
//under ~/a.js
import * as obj from './application'
obj(});
//import * as obj from './application'
//^^^^^^
//
//SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

```
//under ~/a.js
const findFruit = require('./application').default;
console.log(findFruit())
//no problem
```